# Python: dict within dict, wildcard first key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to match data for dict within dict. This:

```
print(a["myval"]["val1"])
```

works to get the desired output.
However I would like to "wildcard" the `myval` entry. To also output the result of `myval2`

```
print(a['*']["val1"])
```

This doesn't work however.

My current method seems clunky:

```
for i in iter(a):
       print(i)
       print(a[i]["val1"])
```

it also breaks when I select `val3`. This is my dict

```
a = {
        "myval" : {
                "val1" : True,
                "val2" : 1,
        },
        "myval2" : {
                "val1" : False,
                "val2" : 0,
                "val3" : [1, 2, 3],
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dicts do not support wildcards in Python. However, you could try something like this:

```
desired_key = "val3"
vals = [ a[key][desired_key] for key in a.keys() if desired_key in a[key] ]
```

This will create an array of all the second layer elements under a certain second layer key, if the key exists.

Comment: NB: You could just use `for key in a` instead of `for key in a.keys()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a version of this yourself by setting `a['*']` to a function that will act as a wildcard.

```py
def getAll(your_dict, search_for):
  values = []
  for key, value in your_dict.items():
    if type(value) == dict and  search_for in value:
      values.append(value[search_for])
  return values

a = {
        "myval" : {
                "val1" : True,
                "val2" : 1,
        },
        "myval2" : {
                "val1" : False,
                "val2" : 0,
                "val3" : [1, 2, 3],
        },
        "*": lambda key: getAll(a, key)
}
```

And then call it with

```
a['*']('val1')  # >>> [True, False]
```

You're setting `a['*']` to a function that will return an array of values, taken from all inner dicts.

Comment: If you're already going this route may as well put a special object there that supports the use of normal indexing so they're really able to do `a['*']['val1']`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution similar to Michael Bianconi's answer that will allow you to use the resulting object exactly like that:

```
class UniversalIndexer:
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.dct = dct

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return [self.dct[key][item] for key in self.dct if key != "*"]

a = {
    "myval" : {
        "val1" : True,
        "val2" : 1,
    },
    "myval2" : {
        "val1" : False,
        "val2" : 0,
        "val3" : [1, 2, 3],
    }
}
a["*"] = UniversalIndexer(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

As already told, dictionaries don't natively support wildcards, and generally I would not recommend such an approach (the answer of tituszban is the straight-forward, Pythonic way to go). However, just for fun and learning purposes, here's a solution that might be useful for hobby projects.

My solution is based on two previous answers, which I should credit:

- Michael Bianconi wrote the first solution: adding a method manually to each dictionary instance. The result should be used a function instead of index (which changes the intended use a bit, IMHO).
- L3viathan improved this solution by returning a custom `UniversalIndexer` object instead of function, thereby mimicking the normal use of a dictionary.

I further extended this solution to create a `MultiDict` class, which behaves like a normal dictionary, but overrides the behavior for the asterisk. Consequently, you don't need to add it manually for each instance. Another advantage is that the dictionary does not actually contain the extra `'*'` key, so iterating over it still works as expected (i.e. you don't have to filter out this special key). I also implemented the `__setitem__()` method, so that you could assign values using the wildcard.

```py
class UniversalIndexer:

    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.dct = dct

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return [self.dct[dkey][key] for dkey in self.dct]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        for dkey in self.dct:
            self.dct[dkey][key] = value


class MultiDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == '*':
            return UniversalIndexer(self)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)


# TEST/DEMONSTRATION CODE:

a = MultiDict({
    'myval': {
        'val1': True,
        'val2': 1,
    },
    'myval2': {
        'val1': False,
        'val2': 0,
        'val3': [1, 2, 3],
    }
})

print(a['myval']['val1'])  # True
print(a['*']['val1'])      # [True, False]

a['*']['val4'] = 10
print(a['*']['val4'])      # [10, 10]
print(list(a.keys()))      # ['myval', 'myval2']
```